# Certificate errors after changing docker location on windows

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox

I've moved my docker location from my C:\ drive to another drive. I did this initially by removing the docker machine (docker-machine rm) and creating a new one ($ docker-machine --storage-path "D:\users\me\.docker\machine" create --driver virtualbox default).

I also set the environment variable MACHINE_STORAGE_PATH="D:\users\me\.docker\machine" which was needed to get docker to see the newly created machine.

Now when I run, for example, docker images, I get the following error:

> Could not read CA certificate
>   "C:\Users\me\.docker\machine\machines\default\ca.pem":
>   open C:\Users\me.docker\machine\machines\default\ca.pem: The system
>   cannot find the path specified.

As you can see docker is looking in the old location for the pem file.

I'm on windows 7
VirtualBox Version 5.0.14 r105127
Docker version 1.10.1, build 9e83765

Comment: Would a `docker-machine regenerate-certs <amachine>` help? Or would it still try and recreate new certif in the old place?

Comment: Have you tried a `docker-machine env <machinename>` or explicitly setting the `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` environment variable?

Comment: regenerate-certs <name> didn't help, I tried setting the path and it doesn't help even though I'm certain I've typed it in correctly and now looks like it's looking in the right place (still doesn't find it), docker-machine env <name> didn't fix it either (and the ca.pem file is there I can see it!)

Comment: Got it! setting DOCKER_CERT_PATH works, just need the right format:  export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=D:\\users\\me\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default

Comment: I have possible answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57702861/5088735). Feel free to try if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting DOCKER_CERT_PATH to the location of ca.pem fixed it for me:

export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=D:\\users\\me\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default

(This is from the docker bash shell)

Answer (score 1):

Copy certificates from "..\.docker\machine\certs"

Paste certificates to "..\.docker\machine\machines\default"

If you have created new machine lets say "dev" then copy to  "..\.docker\machine\machines\dev"